# how to transfer prompt box input data to serlvet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I would like to transfer prompt box input data to servlet.
My process is calling the javascript function for form validation. If the form data is valid, I'll ask the common name by prompt box. I want to transfer with this name to the servlet and I'll get this name by the servlet.
Is this process true or not? If true, how do I transfer this prompt box input data to servlet? I didn't use Ajax.

**ံJSP Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>TESTING!!!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
     var email=document.frm.email.value;
     var password = document.frm.password.value;
     var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

     var result = true;
     if(email==null || email==""){
     alert("fill email address");
    document.frm.email.focus();
    result = false;
    }else if(file==null || file == "" ){
    alert("choose file");
    document.frm.fName.focus();
    result = false;
    }else if(password==null || password == "" ){
    alert("fill password");
    document.frm.password.focus();
    result = false;
    }else if (reg.test(email)==false){
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    document.frm.email.focus();
    result = false;
    }else{
     var cn = prompt('Common Name', '');
     if(cn) alert("Common Name is " +cn);
     result = true;
    }
    return result;                  
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="frm" action="test" method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <p>Email : <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Password : <input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The answer depends on how you are sending the data, is it a normal form posting or an AJAX call?

Comment: Not very clear from your question. Can you give some more explanation?

Comment: Are you sending the data to servlet through ajax?

Comment: Post your sample html and javascript here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is the modified code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>TESTING!!!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
     var email=document.frm.email.value;
     var password = document.frm.password.value;
     var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

     var result = true;
     if(email==null || email==""){
     alert("fill email address");
    document.frm.email.focus();
    result = false;
    }else if(file==null || file == "" ){
    alert("choose file");
    document.frm.fName.focus();
    result = false;
    }else if(password==null || password == "" ){
    alert("fill password");
    document.frm.password.focus();
    result = false;
    }else if (reg.test(email)==false){
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    document.frm.email.focus();
    result = false;
    }else{
     var cn = prompt('Common Name', '');
     if(cn) alert("Common Name is " +cn);
     document.frm.commonName.value = cn; // assigning propt value to hidden field 
     result = true;
    }
    return result;                  
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="frm" action="test" method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <p>Email : <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Password : <input type="password" name="password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    <!-- hidden field for commonName -->
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="commonName" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this :

For example :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function call(){
       var name = prompt('Common Name', '');
       window.location.replace("a.jsp?name="+name);
    }
</script>
```

Then from jsp you can call the sevlet and use the value...